# What happens if customer uploads exceed my data limit?

Tags: cognito-forms

In Cognito Forms, what happens if the cumulative size of many customer upload files exceeds the data limit of my plan?

Will the next customer that attempts an upload receive a message stating that they are denied the ability to upload?

Could I download the files to my local storage and delete them from Cognito as they arrive in order to stay below the data limit?

Answer (score 2):

When enforcing plan limits in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) our goal was to ensure that submissions would always keep flowing in no matter what.  For this reason, when entry storage exceeds plan limits, new entries with attachments are definitely allowed.

When your organization exceeds these limits, you will no longer be allowed to download uploaded files.  However, you can simply [upgrade](https://www.cognitoforms.com/pricing) to a better plan or delete entries to reduce your storage use.